# Calling methods from other activities

Tags: java, android, oop, subclass

I have multiple activities

```
 Activity B extends A
 C extends Activity
 D extends Activity
```

In my app, Activity B might want to call specific item from the OptionsMenu of activities C or D. I would like to change this so that in C and D's OptionsMenu they call methods and B would call these methods as well. How would I organize this?

Comment: How would you "call [an] item"? The code performed by these items may be called, but not the items themselves. In fact, it may be the case that only one `Activity` exists at some point, so you won't be able to call them in this fashion.

Comment: In my app, Activity B never closes (I know I shouldnt do that, but it does). A method in B calls a method that itself calls a thread to be created. That thread, using the context of the current running activity (activity C or D), then calls the execution of an optionsmenu item.

Comment: I'd move the logic out of C and D and into somewhere else, passing to it the necessary data. Keep in mind, Android can, at any point, say "Activity B is taking too much memory" and nix it if C or D is in the foreground.